# debug Mvc view in vs 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on Mvc 5 on VS 2012.

However, I am unable to debug views (.cshtml) files.
Even the intelligence is not working in views.
I am able to debug other source code except views.

can somebody advise what could be the issue?

Comment: surely you cant just becoz its html but you can if you have razor code embedded into html  .

Comment: Thats what I meant.. I have razor in my views and I am not able to debug that. Intelligence also not enabled..

Comment: well ok . if you dont mind keep `@if( // you code )` keep a break point at IF and let me know is that working

Comment: hmmm..since the engine does not recognizes the code, we can not keep break point either..

Comment: oops .! i am sure the break points works if u try to keep it at @if .. worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I can debug MVC Views only from IE meaning I have to select Internet Explorer from VS menu to run the project. Set debug pointer in Views then it works.

[image]